# Corsair Vengeance K70 media keys don't work with Spotify (OSX)

Tags: macos, keyboard, osx-mavericks, spotify

Keys: `back` `next` `play/pause` work fine with iTunes, but only `play/pause` works with Spotify. Connected via USB running 10.9.4.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @ClarkT. no, I didn't :(